# Silverlight MVVM listbox set to horizontal scroll - how to capture mousewheel and scroll the listbox from viewmodel?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, listbox, scroll

Silverlight MVVM listbox set to horizontal scroll - how to capture mousewheel and scroll the listbox from viewmodel ?

Note-- I don't want to select a new item for the user... As they may wish to keep the selection they already have, but are curious about the rest of the options in the listbox that are out of view...

I know that I can use MVVM Light's Event to Command (Thanks Laurent !)... But how to effect the scrolling of the listbox from the viewmodel ?

Thanks
Greg

Comment: Is there a reason why the listbox's own mousewheel scrolling doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind to the offsets of a scrollviewer you can use the technique detailed here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/07/exposing-and-binding-to-a-silverlight-scrollviewer%E2%80%99s-scrollbars/

I have not tried using this on a ListBox, however, the ListBox will use a ScrollViewer internally, so this technique should work.

This, in combination with the event-to-command pattern might give you what you need.